# Is it possible to include/use directly perl's Nagios::Plugin without installing it?

Tags: perl, nagios

I am a web developer needing to monitor a vast array of servers with nagios and have to write some perl scripts for it.

Looking into it I found Nagios::Plugin package from CPAN, but the servers don't have it, and  I am not allowed to do a CPAN install (not even sure all of them have it) much less do a make, make install.

I guess probably there's a way to just download the tarball, uncompress it, and include/require it withing your perl script, don't know maybe specifying the absolute path and such.

Thanks!

I found this script to look for the packages Nagios::Plugin, but to no avail

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

eval { require Nagios::Plugin && Nagios::Plugin->import };
if ($@) {
# assume a relatively recent Perl where FindBin is in core
no warnings;
require FindBin;
unshift @INC, map "$FindBin::Bin/$_",
qw(perl lib perl/lib ../perl ../lib ../perl/lib);
local $" = "\n\t";
eval {
require Nagios::Plugin && Nagios::Plugin->import
}
or die "Couldn't locate Nagios::Plugin in \n\t@INC\n";
}
```

Comment: This could be what you are looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251705/how-can-i-use-a-new-perl-module-without-install-permissions

Comment: You state that you are a web developer and that you are not allowed to have CPAN installed on your web servers (presumably by your operations or systems teams). You should work with them to see what kind of monitoring services are available in your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a pure-perl module, so yes, in theory you could unpack it and load it without running make.  Note that you'd need to already have all the required modules listed in Makefile.PL or the module won't work.

If you unpack it into ~/Nagios-Plugin-0.36/, and your script is in ~/script, then you could do:

mkdir ~/script/lib

cp -R ~/Nagios-Plugin-0.36/lib/ ~/script/lib/

And then the script snippet you posted above should be able to load the module.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much, trying it right now... (yeah the dependencies are a concern)

Answer (score 1):

This particular package is in the EPEL repository for Red Hat based systems, so if you're managing those you could simply install the `perl-Nagios-Plugin` RPM.

Comment: Indeed the servers are running centos, but there's still the issue of not being allowed to install stuff.

Comment: If they won't let you install an RPM package, you need to fix the business process first.